# How should I make a new instance of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I would like to make an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) which contains [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html)s.

```java
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

The code is underlined and NetBeans says: *"Redundant type arguments in new expression (use diamond operator instead)."*

What does it mean?

Comment: It means that you can remove `Object` on the right side of the assignment. Like this: `ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: `List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();` you don't need to repeat `Object`, the compiler can infer it, therefore it is redundant. `<>` is the diamond operator

Comment: Partly yes, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you can rewrite the line of code like this:

```
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
```

and it will work the same.